# WPF TabControl On SelectionChanged, set focus to a text field

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, tabs, selectionchanged

I have a tab control, and a few tab items. I am successfully listening to the `SelectionChanged` event, and checking if the tab I'm interested in is the currently selected one.

I'm using this code (below), and stepping through the debugger, I can see that my branching logic works as designed; however, the issue I'm having is that something is overriding this call to `txt.Focus()` because after the correct tab item is displayed, the focus is not on the text box.

```
private void tabMain_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // exact same behavior with and without this line
    e.Handled = true;

    if (e.AddedItems.Contains(usrTab))
    {
        txtusr.Focus();
    }
    else if (e.AddedItems.Contains(svcTab))
    {
        txtsvc.Focus();
    }
}
```

If I just put `txtusr.Focus()` in a button event handler, it focuses exactly as I'd expect.

I suspect that this has to do with the tabitem content not being loaded at the time the `.Focus()` method is called, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Have you isolated the problem external to your code to see if it is reproducible? If so, it's a timing/framework issue and then you can approach the problem a bit differently with that knowledge in hand.

Comment: I was able to inconsistantly reproduce this in a stub-program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try putting the .Focus() calls inside a dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { txtsvc.Focus(); }));
```

Comment: I was not getting a threading exception, but this has fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Yah, in this case it's not really about threads.  Some controls use Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke internally.  By adding your task to the end of the Dispatcher queue, you allow everything before it to finish up (as long as your task is of equal or lower priority than everything else).  That's my understanding at least.